# Converting points gained to hours played (Math related)

Tags: javascript, math, data-conversion

I need to use plain JavaScript to convert an amount of experience points to an amount of hours played by a number of fixed rates.

For example:

A player has 1,129,518 experience points.

The amount of experience points that are gained per hour depends on the amount of xp one already has. They would be arranged something like this:

above 0 xp: 8,000 xp/h

above 2,107 xp: 20,000 xp/h

above 101,333 xp: 45,000 xp/h

above 1,210,421 xp: 68,500 xp/h

above 13,034,431 xp: 75,000 xp/h

I'm struggling to find a way to use these xp rates to convert a given amount of experience points to hours played, using at least somewhat elegant Javascript.

I just end up with a cunfusing mess of if/else statements that ends up failing because of math errors.

Any Math wizards out there that can help me? Thanks.

Code Sample: I would go from here

```
 if(xp === 0){
    return 0;
}else if( 2107 >= xp > 0){
    const result = (xp/8000).toFixed(1);
    return result;
}else if(101333 >= xp > 2107){
    const result = ((2107/8000) + ((xp-2107)/20000)).toFixed(1);
    return result;
}else if(1210421 >= xp > 101333){
    ...
}
```

As you can see it would quickly get out of hand if theres alot of different tiers.

Comment: Can you show that "confusing mess"?

Comment: edited the original post :)

Comment: Regardless of the math issues, please don't use `.toFixed(1)` to round numbers.   Its only legitimate purpose is for converting numbers to fixed decimal _string format_ for display on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should write your if statements like this:

```
if( 2107 >= xp && xp > 0){
    ...
}
```

Next, try thinking about XP as buckets of XP and each bucket having different value/price. Go from most valuable bucket to least valuable, and for each bucket calculate hours and subtract amount of XP that was used to calculate those hours.

You can do this in while loop:

```
let hours = 0;
while(XP > 0)
{
  // figure out bucket you are in, your if statements are fine for that.
  let value = 0;
  let lowerBoundary = 0;
  if( 101333 >= xp && xp > 2107){
    value = 20000;
    lowerBoundary = 2107;
    // you need lower boundary to figure out how many XP you used in this bucket.
  }
  // else if...
  const usedInBucket = XP - lowerBoundary;
  hours += usedInBucket / value; // simply calculate hours needed
  XP -= usedInBucket;
}
```

Comment: This looks fabulous! I'll give it a try when I'm back at home later, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```js
const steps = [{
    min: 0,
    val: 8000
  },
  {
    min: 2107,
    val: 20000
  },
  {
    min: 101333,
    val: 45000
  },
  {
    min: 1210421,
    val: 68500
  },
  {
    min: 13034431,
    val: 75000
  },
].sort((a, b) => b.min - a.min);

//using for loop
function xpToHours(xp = 0) {
  let h = 0;
  steps.forEach(s => {
    let amt = Math.max(xp - s.min, 0);
    h += amt * s.val;
    xp -= amt;
  });
  return h;
}

//using reduce
function xpToHours2(xp = 0) {
  return steps.reduce((h, s) => {
    let amt = Math.max(xp - s.min, 0);
    xp -= amt;
    return h + amt * s.val;
  }, 0)
}


[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 1000000].forEach(xp => console.log(xp, xpToHours(xp)));
[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 1000000].forEach(xp => console.log(xp, xpToHours2(xp)));
```

To explain:

`steps` is just an array containing your different stages. It is sorted by the minimum xp from highest to lowest.

Then we just iterate over this array calculating `amt` which is the xp used up by the currently highest stage. The needed time is therefore `amt * currentstep.val` and the xp is reduced by the calculated amount for the next stage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a sorted array of ranges and [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
// Make sure this is sorted desc
const expRanges = [{
    above: 101333,
    xph: 45000
  },
  {
    above: 2107,
    xph: 20000
  },
  {
    above: 0,
    xph: 8000
  }
];

function findExpPerHour(xp) {
  return expRanges.find(range => range.above < xp).xph;
}

// TESTS
const playerExpTests = [{
  name: "P1",
  xp: 12
}, {
  name: "P2",
  xp: 12000
}, {
  name: "P3",
  xp: 200000
}, {
  name: "P4",
  xp: 99999999
}];

playerExpTests.forEach(p => {
  console.log(p.name, "Exp per hour:", findExpPerHour(p.xp));
});
```